# Dynamo db appending distinct maps to the list using Update_item

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I used Dynamo db `update_item` operation in combination with `list_append` to get the output like this.

here is the code which will give

```
temp_response = table.update_item(
                Key={
                        primary: <primary>,
                        seconday: <secondary>
                },
                UpdateExpression="SET info = if_not_exists(info, :empty_dict)",
                ExpressionAttributeValues={":empty_dict": {}}
            )

final_response = table.update_item(
                Key={
                primary:<primary>,
                secondary:<secondary>
                },
                UpdateExpression="SET info.users = list_append(if_not_exists("
                                 "info.users, :empty_list), :my_value)",
                ExpressionAttributeValues={":my_value": [<user-map>], ":empty_list": []}

            )
```

```
Item {3} 
    info Map{1}
        users List[3]
           0 Map {3}
             name :aaa
             id   :111
             gender:male
           1 Map {3}
             name :bbb
             id   :222
             gender:female
           2 Map {3}
             name :aaa
             id   :111
             gender:male
    primary: 88888
    secondary:999
```

here `list_append` operation simply  append `new maps` to the `users` list.

Problem: If you see `users` list `map-0` and `map-2` consists of same data. so here we see duplicate maps.

**How can i make sure `maps` inside the `users` are distinct**

**I want like this**

```
Item {3} 
    info Map{1}
        users List[3]
           0 Map {3}
             name :aaa
             id   :111
             gender:male
           1 Map {3}
             name :bbb
             id   :222
             gender:female
    primary: 88888
    secondary:999
```

**Can anyone please suggest some solution?**

Comment: You could try a [conditional update](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html#Expressions.ConditionExpressions.SimpleComparisons), but, AFAIK, you'd need to have a field in the map which is a unique key (maybe `id`), and you'd need to keep a separate flat list of IDs as strings, which you could then include in the condition expression (`IN` operator).

Comment: Hi  Rafael Almeida,
Initially, I don't have any info about what values I will receive and another thing, continuously i will receive data from outer sources so, i want a logic that will continiously store distinct maps in the dynamo db.

Comment: Hi  Rafael Almeida,

I added my code snippet, please find it. if you have any suggestions how i can improve the logic that would be appreciated.